# Precision Error while converting dollars/gallon to dollars/liter and back

Tags: java, bigdecimal, rounding-error

The following code has a precision error but I'm at a loss as to how to resolve it.  Given an initial value set in dollar/gal of $3.95, when change the ChoiceBox to "dollars/liter" I get $1.04, but when I change it back to dollar/gal I'm getting $3.94 instead of $3.95

```
if ("dollar/gal".equals(newValue)) {
   double pricePerLiter = Double.parseDouble(txtFields.get(1).getText());
   BigDecimal pricePerGallon =  BigDecimal.valueOf(pricePerLiter * 3.785);                        
   pricePerGallon = pricePerGallon.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);                        
   txtFields.get(1).setText(pricePerGallon.toString());

} else if ("dollars/liter".equals(newValue)) {

  double pricePerGallon = Double.parseDouble(txtFields.get(1).getText());                        
  BigDecimal pricePerLiter = BigDecimal.valueOf(pricePerGallon * 0.264);                        
  pricePerLiter = pricePerLiter.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
  txtFields.get(1).setText(pricePerLiter.toString());
}
```

I've attempted this with both Math.Round() and BigDecimal and RoundingMode (which is the version above) but cannot resolve this issue.

Comment: You lost precision when you overwrite your original price with the rounded price.

Comment: There are 3.785411784 liters in a gallon. You could also divide by that going the other way, instead of multiplying by the inverse truncated to three sig figs.

Comment: Of course, if you truncate the price to three sig figs, that's all the significance you'll have. Any further precision is lost, as jxh points out.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a floating-point representation issue; it's a rounding issue.  When you round, your value is no longer accurate.  In addition, the two values you multiply with don't themselves multiply to be 1; they're not quite inverses.

When you take `3.95` and multiply it by `0.264`, the value is `1.0428`, which you round down to `1.04`.  When you multiply `1.04` by `3.785`, you get `3.9364`, which is rounded up to `3.94`.

But you represent the inverse of `3.785` as `0.264`, which is close, but not quite equal to the actual inverse of about `0.2642008`.  But even multiplying the true inverse value by `3.95` you get `1.04359316`, which you would still round down to `1.04`.

If you must convert back to the same value, then store the un-rounded value for multiplying later, even if you display the rounded value.  Also, instead of multiplying by `0.264`, just divide by the same number that you multiplied by in the other case, `3.785`.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you are using floating point (`double`, `float`) you lost your precision after the period, the so called *scale* (10<sup>**-3**</sup> here for 3.785).

So do not use the `BigDecimal` constructor with a `double` but with a `String`. Then the scale, digits after the period, will be specified.

```
BigDecimal pricePerLiter = new BigDecimal(txtFields.get(1).getText());
BigDecimal pricePerGallon =  pricePerLiter.multiply(new BigDecimal("3.785"));
```

So "1.00" * "3.785" will become "3.78500".
This cannot be achieved by a double 3.785 as that is an approximation, maybe equal to 3.7849999998.

So either use only `BigDecimal` or use the imprecise `double` and print a rounded text: `Sytem.out.printf("%5.2f", 3.785); // 3.79`.